# How can i make a pop-up window with checkboxes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, popupwindow

I am trying to make a button that opens a pop-up window when it is clicked. It is working, but I would like to add a pop-up window that has three checkboxes. It is an assignment for school, so I can't use any other languages than HTML5, CSS and JavaScript. Is this possible? This is the HTML code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="prijsvraag.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="prijsvraagknop()" value="Prijsvraag"></button>
```

This is the js code

```
function prijsvraagknop(){
var naam = window.prompt("Jouw naam:")
var jouw_antwoord = window.prompt("Jouw reactie:")

if (document.getElementById('B').checked) {
    alert("Hoera " + NaamVar + "! Je hebt het antwoord goed. Er doen nog meer kinderen mee. Je kunt daarom over een maand op deze pagina lezen of je de hoofdprijs gewonnen hebt.");
    }
else {
    alert("Helaas " + NaamVar + ". Je hebt het antwoord fout. Je maakt geen kans op de hoofdprijs.");
    }
```

Comment: You can't with native-browser functionality. You will need create some custom JavaScript to make the popup allow custom rendering

Comment: You can use window.open with a second HTML page to accomplish this.

Comment: Create modal window using just [js and css](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example.The `html` code consist of checkboxes shown below.

```
<input type="button" id="popupbutton" onclick="popup(this)"/>
    <ul id="checkBundle">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" />test1</label>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" />test2</label>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" />test3</label>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" />test4</label>
     </ul>
```

The javascript is below

```
  function popup() {
       var popwindow = document.getElementById("checkBundle");
       if (popwindow.style.display === "none") {
           popwindow.style.display = "block";
      } else {
            popwindow.style.display = "none";
        }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a mechanism to open the popup window.  That same mechanism can be used to set a visibility flag on a div that contains the checkboxes.

where-as your onClick would lead to your alert or confirm call, rendering your popup.  Your onClick would set a visibility flag on the div with the checkboxes.